# Extjs 4 new line

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hello I have a string that contains `<br/>` tags for new line. It looks like this :

```
   "s = rod/Rel = ecc 6.7.3 6.5.0 6.7.0 6.7.1 6.6.0 6.7.2 6.2.0 6.1.0<br />Metric =   Backlog<br />Severity = minor<br />Views = Monthly<br />"
```

I want to use it inside a text sprite, but it seems like the text doesn't understand the html tags. How can I do it please?

```
 var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
            type: 'text',
            surface: chart.surface,
            text: Ext.util.Format.format('Metric generated with : '+ s),
            font: '12px Arial',
            x: 50,
            y: 10,
            width: 100,
            height: 100 
        });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using: `\n` for linbreaks instead of `<br/>`

```
"s = rod/Rel = ecc 6.7.3 6.5.0 6.7.0 6.7.1 6.6.0 6.7.2 6.2.0 6.1.0\nMetric =   Backlog\nSeverity = minor\nViews = Monthly\n"
```

Comment: try removing `type: 'text',`

Comment: i had to completely "rephrase" my answer sorry. Just realised you can't use `html` in `Ext.draw`